# (How) Can I remove a word from a DFA?

Tags: finite-automata

As the title says, is it possible to remove a word from a DFA? One obvious way is to calculate the language without the word that I want to remove and then construct the DFA for the updated language. What I am interested in is whether there is a way to just update the original automaton without constructing another automaton from scratch.

For example, suppose that I have the automaton

[image]

And I want to remove *bab*, but words such as *baab* should still be accepted. Obviously removing any of the transitions directly would cut a lot more words than what I intend and a solution doesn't seem obvious. Are there any known algorithms for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the regular languages $L, L'$, based on the DFA for $L,L'$ we can:

1. make an DFA for the complement of a language $\overline L$, and
2. construct a DFA for the intersection $L \cap L'$.

The first is done by converting all the accepting states to non-accepting and vice-versa. The second can be done by calculating the intersection of two DFA's.

This gives an algorithmic way to express a DFA for your DFA $L_1$, and the language $L_2=\{bab\}$, by calculating the automata for $L_1\cap \overline{L_2}$.

The only thing left to do is construct a DFA for the $L_2$ and follow the procedure.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an algorithm that should work (unfortunately, I don't know how to write a satisfactory proof):

The idea is to create a bad path through the graph so that the specific word you want to remove does not end up in a final state. Care must be taken so that this path is not reachable from any other state other than the initial one (i.e. for each state in the bad path, there is *exactly one* in-edge to it, which is coming from another state in the bad path; except for the initial state, which has no in-edges).

1. - set the current state, $crt$, to be the initial state
   - set the previous state $prev$, to $null$
   - set the current symbol, $sym$ to be the first symbol of the word you need to eliminate (or the special value $\\\$$ if it's the empty word)$^1$
   - set the previous symbol, $psym$, to $null$.
2. make a copy of the current state;

   - if the current state was the initial state, the copy is now initial, the original one becomes non-initial
   - if $prev$ and $psym$ are not $null$, draw an edge from $prev$ to the copy, on the symbol $psym$.
3. if $sym$ = \$:

   - make the copy non-final; for each symbol in the alphabet draw an edge from the copy to the destination of $state$; DONE
   - otherwise preserve its finality.
4. For each symbol $\sigma$ in the alphabet:

   - if $\sigma \neq sym$: draw a $\sigma$ edge from the copy to the same destination as $crt$
   - else:

     - $prev \leftarrow state$
     - $psym \leftarrow sym$
     - set $state$ to be the destination of $\sigma$ from $state$
     - set $sym$ to be the next symbol (or the special value $\\\$$ if the end was reached).
5. goto 2

For your example you'd end up with:

[image]

---

$^1$ $\\\$$ is useful to generalize for the case of the empty word; $\\\$$ should be a symbol that is not part of the DFA's alphabet.

Comment: Thanks! However, "bab" is still accepted in this automaton and other strings that should be accepted (such as baab) are rejected... Also, steps 1 and 2 look like they are dependent on the specific example and not for a general case, unless I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I somehow misread your question; the automaton provided actually removed "baab", not "bab". Steps 1 and 2 are based on *a* specific example, that being the word you want to reject, but it's not a concrete word. However, I now see that I forgot to consider the empty word, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Now you reject "baaab" that should be accepted based on the original :) What I meant about steps 1 and 2 was that if for example in the starting automaton the initial state wasn't marked your solution would have still marked it regardless of what happens in the original (again, if I am not misunderstanding).

Comment: You're right; my algorithm was half-thought. Marking states was unneeded, you need to make a copy as soon as you encounter them (the marking was something internal to the algorithm, btw, it wasn't about finality). I've completely rewritten my answer.